# why I get "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, iterable

I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` when I run this code, what's wrong?

```
# Write a function called nested_sum that
# takes a nested list of integers and add up
# the elements from all of the nested lists.

def nested_sum(lista):
    total = 0
    for item in lista:
       item = sum(item)
       total = total + item
    return total
list1 = [ 1 , 2  ,3 , [7, 3] ]
nested_sum(list1)
```

Comment: Because you're doing `sum(1)`.

Comment: I thought sum(1) should give 1 as a result, what is wrong with that? thanks

Comment: `return sum([ (nested_sum(x) if isinstance(x,list) else x) for x in lista])`

Answer (score 0):

The function **sum** takes an iterator as a parameter. In line 8 of your code, you are using sum with an int. Your **list1** array contains numbers and an array.
You can find information about the sum function [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Statement**

Write a function called nested_sum that takes a nested list of integers and add up the elements from all of the nested lists.

**OP Attempt**

```
def nested_sum(lista):
    total = 0
    for item in lista:
       item = sum(item)
       total = total + item
    return total
list1 = [ 1 , 2  ,3 , [7, 3] ]
nested_sum(list1)
```

**Answer**

You've made a good attempt at solving the problem, but you are getting that `TypeError` because you are calling the `sum` function with an argument that the `sum` function is not designed to be called with.

I would encourage you to read the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum) covering the `sum` function. But, I'll give you a little explanation here as well.

The `sum` function takes at most two arguments. The first argument must be an object that is `iterable`. Some examples of iterable objects are `list`s, `dict`s, and `set`s. If it's a collection of some sort, then it's probably a safe assumption that it's iterable. The second argument to the sum function is optional. It's a number that represents the first number you'll start adding to. If you omit the second argument, then you'll start adding to 0. The second argument isn't relevant for your function, so you can ignore it in this case.

With that in mind, you should now be able to see why calling the `sum` function with an `int` as the first argument causes the Python interpreter to throw an error.

```
def nested_sum(lista):
    total = 0
    for item in lista:
       item = sum(item) # The error is here
       total = total + item
    return total
list1 = [ 1 , 2  ,3 , [7, 3] ]
nested_sum(list1)
```

You can fix the error using @JacobIRR's answer, which is to replace the problem line with:

`item = sum(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item`

However, that line could be a bit confusing to some, so I'll take the liberty of making it more obvious.

```
def nested_sum(lista):
    total = 0
    for item in lista:
       if isinstance(item, list): # if the item is a list
           item = sum(item)       # sum the list
       total += item              # total = total + item
    return total
list1 = [ 1 , 2  ,3 , [7, 3] ]
nested_sum(list1)
```

Also, while this piece of code might work for the example list you provided. Consider what would happen if you called your function with a list that is nested even further.

Eg. `list1 = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, [6, 7]]]`

I hope this not only helps you solve your problem, but also understand how the `sum` function is meant to be used.

Answer (score -1):

sum() takes a list as its args.

You could change the problem line to:

```
item = sum(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also just make your own function recursive since you have to make a sum function yourself anyway. Why use another function when you wrote a function to do the exact same thing?

```
def nested_sum(lista):
total = 0
for item in lista:
   if isinstance(item, list) or isinstance(item, tuple):
      item = nested_sum(item)
   total = total + item
return total
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. I've run the code and it works quite fine. Nor why all the other answers in this thread were downvoted. They all seem reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

You can't sum this:

```
l = [1,2,3,[4,5]]
sum(1)
```

A solution:

```
def nested_sum(ls):
    total = 0
    for e in ls:
       if not isinstance(e, int):
           items = sum(e)
           total += items
       else:
           items = e
           total += items
    return total
```